# Javascript is taking two clicks to initialize what I would like it to do

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a basic function that on click will allow a button that I have created to change its background color from a standard light gray I set with css to red with each click it should change from one to the other or vice versa. the issue I'm having is on the first click it stays light gray then the second click will turn it red and from there it will toggle on one click.

I'm trying this as a standard function "forgive me if that's not proper jargon for it" I'm also curious as to how this can be done as an arrow function since that was I could get it to change from light gray to red but not back to light gray.

```
let redBtn = document.getElementById('redBtn');
redBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 const bgColor = redBtn.style.background;
  if (bgColor == 'lightgray') {
   redBtn.style.background = 'red';
  } else {
  redBtn.style.background = 'lightgray';
 }
 });
```

also the arrow function if you wouldn't mind providing insight to this issue as well thanks!

```
let red = document.getElementById('redBtn');
 red.addEventListener('click', () => {
  red.style.background = 'red';
  if (red == 'lightgray') {
  red.style.background = 'red';
  } else {
  red.style.background = 'lightgray';   
 `enter code here` });
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feed back I was able to get it to work on the first 'click' !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first click, accessing the `background` property will return the empty string, even if CSS has set it to `lightgray`:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('div').style.background === ''
);
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

If you want to change it to `red` when the background is `lightgray`, check for if it's `lightgray` *or* the empty string:

```
let redBtn = document.getElementById('redBtn');
redBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const bgColor = redBtn.style.background;
  if (bgColor == 'lightgray' || bgColor === '') {
    redBtn.style.background = 'red';
  } else {
    redBtn.style.background = 'lightgray';
  }
});
```

Or, it might be nicer to switch around the `if`/`else` - just check to see if the background is `red`, and if so, assign to `lightgray`. You can use the conditional operator here to reduce the amount of code, if you wanted:

```
let redBtn = document.getElementById('redBtn');
redBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const bgColor = redBtn.style.background;
  redBtn.style.background = bgColor === 'red'
  ? 'lightgray'
  : 'red';
});
```

An arrow function makes no difference here, because you're not referencing `this` or calling the function as a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
const bgColor = redBtn.style.background;
```

Returns more than just the color. In fact it returns a string with up to eight properties.
So upon your first click, it doesn't match "lightgray" because the string it returns might be e.g. "lightgray none repeat scroll 0% 0%".

To only get the background color use this:

```
const bgColor = redBtn.style.backgroundColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's set the background to red like you wanted first:

```
// You wanted a function, so we added the onclick=""
<button id="redBtn" onclick="change()" style="background: red">Click</button>
```

Since you wanted an arrow function.

```
function change() { }
// Same as
change = () => { }
```

The ternary operator basically is saying:

```
bg === 'red' ? btn.style.background = 'lightgrey' : btn.style.background = 'red';
// Same as
if (background === red) { 
// Change to lightgrey 
} else { 
    // red
}
```

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('redBtn'); // Get button 
// Arrow function
change = () => {
  const bg = btn.style.background; // Grab background color
  // Ternary
  bg === 'red' ? btn.style.background = 'lightgrey' : btn.style.background = 'red';

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<button id="redBtn" onclick="change()" style="background: red">Click</button>
```